# Parse SQS stringify json message Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a SQS queue which triggers a lambda function where as a message I pass the stringify json. I am trying to get the whole message body from the `Records`, but throws an error,

```sh
[ERROR] KeyError: 'efsPathIn'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 20, in lambda_handler
    key = bodyDict['efsPathIn']
```

I'm sending this stringify json as a message in SQS queue,

```sh
{"Records": [{"body": "{\"efsPathIn\": \"163939.jpeg\",\"imageWidth\": \"492\",\"imageHeight\": \"640\",\"bucketOut\":\"output-bucket\",\"keyOut\":\"163939.webp\"}"}]}
```

And the code is which extracts the values,

```sh
for item in event['Records']:
    body = str(item['body'])
    bodyDict = json.loads(body)
    key = bodyDict['efsPathIn']
    bucket_out = bodyDict['bucketOut']
    width = bodyDict['imageWidth']
    height = bodyDict['imageHeight']
    key_out = bodyDict['keyOut']
```

I've tried with `json.dumps(item['body'])` also which further loads the json, but still getting the same error.

When I test from AWS Lambda test console using the above mentioned json message, the function gets successfully executed, but I get this error while sending a message from a SQS queue.

Comment: Are you accessing the message queue contents? Can you share where `event` is coming from? Can you log `event` right before your `for` loop to assert exactly what is in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.dumps()` is for converting a Python object into a JSON string. You have a JSON string that you are need to convert into a Python object. You should be calling `json.loads()` like so:

```
body = json.loads(item['body'])
```

After which you will have a Python object that you can do things like: `body['efsPathIn']`